# Sony WH1000-XM4, no microphone input through bluetooth connection on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, microphone

I have a PC with Ubuntu 18.04 and a usb bluetooth 4.0 adapter. I can connect to my Sony WH-1000XM4 and hear the audio output from my pc. However, its microphone doesn't work at all, although I can see a microphone icon "Headset-WH-1000XM4" in the settings-sound-input tab. I have tried installed the bluez and blueman, as well as set the headphone in both "HFP/HSP" and "A2DP" modes. But neither of them helps...

Wish to hear any suggestion from you, thanks in advance!

Bruce.

Comment: mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.old
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
systemctl restart bluetooth Try this.

Comment: As I've been trying to use the mic of the xm4's on Ubuntu and have stumbled upon a lot of unanswered/ partially answered questions. This guide helped me the most - https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/bluetooth-headphones-ubuntu/ Note: The mic only works in HSP/HFP mode, the audio quality is terrible when in this mode but I mainly use it for meetings so it doesn't really matter to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer but only HFP/HSP supports both sound and mic at same time the other profile does not support mic at all.